# BiMap capabilities of a Guava Cache?

Tags: caching, guava, bimap

I have a simple mapping table in a database that associates integer keys with certain values. Once I stick the values in the table, they never go away. I'd like to use a [Guava `Cache`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) so that these keys can be looked up once and then stay stored in memory. It looks likea Guava `Cache` will allow me to do this easily. However I need to map both ways: from key to value, and from value to key, like a `BiMap`.

Is there a simple way to get `BiMap` functionality using a `Cache`, or will I have to roll my own solution?

Is there a `BiMap` implementation that allows concurrent access, or will I have to use read-write locks if I want efficient, multi-threaded access?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way to get BiMap functionality using a Cache, or will I have to roll my own solution?

There's `Maps.synchronizedBiMap`, but I don't think that it's good starting point, as adding all the `Cache` capabilities is probably way harder than adding the `Bi` to a `Cache`.

It's also just synchronized, not concurrent.

> Is there a BiMap implementation that allows concurrent access,

AFAIK no.

> or will I have to use read-write locks if I want efficient, multi-threaded access?

I guess, it depends of what part of the `BiMap` functionality you need. The `BiMap` allows you

- to `get` and `put` in both directions
- to preserve bijectivity either via `forcePut` or via `put` throwing an exception on conflicts

If you're sure that no conflicts may ever happen, then it's not that complicated. Maybe all you need is to piggyback two caches like I did [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2v0juqjow662ctb/BiMapLikeCache.java?dl=0).

---

AFAIK for preserving bijectivity, you'd need locks. If writes are not too common, then you're done quickly with a single `ReadWriteLock`. Otherwise....

You could try to use `Striped` for maximum concurrency, but I'm afraid, it's too tricky as you'd need to lock a stripe depending on both the key and the value. And also on previous value in case of `forcePut`.

---

Whenever I used `BiMap`, I found out later either that I actually need to get something in more than two different ways (some secondary key) or that I need to get some additional information. So I converted it to two or three maps in a class like

```
void put(K1 k1, K2 k2, E extraInfo) {
    MyEntry<K1, K2, E> e = new MyEntry<>(k1, k2, extraInfo);
    firstMap.put(k1, e);
    secondMap.put(k2, e);
}

MyEntry<K1, K2, E> getByFirstKey(K1 k1);
MyEntry<K1, K2, E> getBySecondKey(K2 k2);
```

It's a bit hacky, but simple and maybe it applies to your cache as well.

Comment: piggy back where? link is 404

Comment: @harschware Fixed.